# perl untar single file

Tags: linux, perl, archive-tar

So running into an issue with my code here not sure what exactly i'm doing wrong i pass it the two arguments it searches for the file but its always going to does not exist.

i pass this to the file

```
perl restore.cgi users_old_52715.tar.gz Ace_Walker
```

its not finding the file it exist i assure you.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Archive::Tar;

my $tarPath    = $ARGV[0];
my $playerfile = $ARGV[1].".ini";



my $tar = Archive::Tar->new($tarPath);
if ($tar->contains_file($playerfile)) {
    $tar->read($tarPath);
    $tar->extract_file($playerfile, './' );
    print "Successfully restored $playerfile to production enviroment\n";
    exit 0;
}else{
    print $playefile." does not exist in this archive!\n";
    exit 0;
}
```

Comment: Try using an absolute path instead of a relative one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just writing [Scott Hunter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/535275/scott-hunter)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31459496/perl-untar-single-file#comment50885972_31459496) as an answer:

> Try using an absolute path instead of a relative one.

Answer (score 0):

```
if( $tar->extract_file($playerfile, './'.$playerfile )){ 
  print "Successfully restored $playerfile to production enviroment\n";
}
exit 0;
```

**`man Archive::Tar`** :

> $tar->extract_file( $file, [$extract_path] )
>          Write an entry, whose name is equivalent to the file name provided to disk. Optionally takes a second parameter, which is the full native path (**including filename**) the entry will be written to.